# Rails ignores association scope when pre-caching with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**TL;DR:** This question has its own sample app at https://github.com/skensell/SO-question-example which you can use to debug yourself.  I put a bounty already once on this question, but I'm not convinced of (or I don't understand) the top answerer's reasoning. I am going to put another bounty on this because it's causing me a lot of frustration.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have a model `User` which has an association like so:

```
has_many :avatars, -> { order([:sort_order => :asc,:created_at => :asc])}
```

I have an endpoint which performs a search for users and sets an `@users` variable to be used by the view.  Here comes the spooky part which I found in the debugger:

```
@users.first.avatars[0..2].map(&:id)
# => [2546, 2547, 2548]
# This is the correct order.

@users.to_a.first.avatars[0..2].map(&:id)
# => [2548, 2546, 2547]
# Wrong order.
```

What is going on here?

The only difference is `to_a`. I even tried leaving out the `to_a`, but I think it's implicitly being called by jbuilder anyways since I set it to a json array.

Maybe the way I'm searching `User` has something to do with it? I'm using several includes and joins.

**UPDATE**

Here I can show you a simple example of this weird behavior from the rails console.  It seems that the includes..references is the offender, but I don't get why or how.

```
User.order(id: :desc)
    .includes(:avatars, :industries)
    .where(industries: {id:  [5]})
    .references(:industries)
    .limit(5).to_a.second.avatars.map(&:id)
# => [2751, 2748, 2749]
# Wrong order.

User.order(id: :desc)
    .includes(:avatars, :industries)
    .where(industries: {id:  [5]})
    .references(:industries)
    .limit(5).second.avatars.map(&:id)
# => [2748, 2749, 2751]
# Correct order.
```

I can verify that these queries refer to the same user, and that the one labeled Correct order is really correct w.r.t `sort_order` and `created_at` (which is how the association specifies the ordering).

**UPDATE 2**

Attached is the requested SQL log. I changed irrelevant fields to "OMITTED" and I replaced 34 irrelevant user fields with a '...'.

```
>> User.order(id: :desc).includes(:avatars, :industries).where(industries: {id:  [5]}).references(:industries).limit(5).to_a.second.avatars.map(&:id)
SQL (18.5ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "users"."id", "users"."id" AS alias_0 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "avatars" ON "avatars"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_professions" ON "user_professions"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_professions"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (5)  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 5
SQL (8.3ms)  SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."OMITTED" AS t0_r1, "users"."OMITTED" AS t0_r2, ... AS t0_r36, "avatars"."id" AS t1_r0, "avatars"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "avatars"."avatar" AS t1_r2, "avatars"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "avatars"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "avatars"."OMITTED" AS t1_r5, "avatars"."OMITTED" AS t1_r6, "avatars"."sort_order" AS t1_r7, "industries"."id" AS t2_r0, "industries"."name" AS t2_r1, "industries"."created_at" AS t2_r2, "industries"."updated_at" AS t2_r3 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "avatars" ON "avatars"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_professions" ON "user_professions"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_professions"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (5) AND "users"."id" IN (1526, 945, 927, 888, 884)  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC
=> [2751, 2748, 2749]

>> User.order(id: :desc).includes(:avatars, :industries).where(industries: {id:  [5]}).references(:industries).limit(5).second.avatars.map(&:id)
SQL (0.9ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "users"."id", "users"."id" AS alias_0 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "avatars" ON "avatars"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_professions" ON "user_professions"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_professions"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (5)  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."OMITTED" AS t0_r1, "users"."OMITTED" AS t0_r2, ... AS t0_r36, "avatars"."id" AS t1_r0, "avatars"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "avatars"."avatar" AS t1_r2, "avatars"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "avatars"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "avatars"."OMITTED" AS t1_r5, "avatars"."OMITTED" AS t1_r6, "avatars"."sort_order" AS t1_r7, "industries"."id" AS t2_r0, "industries"."name" AS t2_r1, "industries"."created_at" AS t2_r2, "industries"."updated_at" AS t2_r3 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "avatars" ON "avatars"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_professions" ON "user_professions"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_professions"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (5) AND "users"."id" IN (945)  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC
=> [2748, 2749, 2751]
>>
```

And here I'll attach a log which shows the user in question's avatars (id, sort_order, and created_at) so you can see that the order should be deterministic.

```
>> User.find(945).avatars.pluck(:id,:sort_order,:created_at)
User Load (5.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 945]]
(0.2ms)  SELECT "avatars"."id", "avatars"."sort_order", "avatars"."created_at" FROM "avatars"  WHERE "avatars"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "avatars"."sort_order" ASC, "avatars"."created_at" ASC  [["user_id", 945]]
=> [[2748, 0, Fri, 13 Nov 2015 00:32:53 UTC +00:00], [2749, 0, Fri, 13 Nov 2015 00:47:02 UTC +00:00], [2751, 0, Fri, 13 Nov 2015 00:48:05 UTC +00:00]]
```

Also, I'm using Rails 4.1.4 and Ruby 2.1.10.

**UPDATE 3**

I have created a sample app here: https://github.com/skensell/SO-question-example . What's even stranger in this sample app is that the `to_a` doesn't even matter. I get the wrong ordering even with just the `includes... references`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Includes considers the order of the parent table whose records are going to be retrieved only when it results in a join query. ie in the above case, the avatars order is going to be skipped and the users order is going to be used when the includes query results in a join. You can add a default scope to User and confirm.

If you still want the user.avatars to be sorted as per the defined avatar orders, you need to replace includes with joins. Note that using join will retrieve duplicate user records.

A working solution to retrieve data as expected is to use joins and includes together.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.2.0 :001 > User.count
(0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
=> 2 
2.2.0 :002 > User.pluck :id, :name
(0.2ms)  SELECT "users"."id", "users"."name" FROM "users"
=> [[1, "John"], [2, "Jill"]] 
2.2.0 :003 > User.first.industries.pluck :id, :name
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  SELECT "industries"."id", "industries"."name" FROM "industries" INNER JOIN "user_industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "user_industries"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
=> [[1, "Art"], [2, "Music"]] 
2.2.0 :004 > User.last.industries.pluck :id, :name
User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  SELECT "industries"."id", "industries"."name" FROM "industries" INNER JOIN "user_industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "user_industries"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
=> [[1, "Art"]] 
2.2.0 :005 > User.first.avatars.pluck :id, :sort_order
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.3ms)  SELECT "avatars"."id", "avatars"."sort_order" FROM "avatars"  WHERE "avatars"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "avatars"."sort_order" ASC, "avatars"."created_at" ASC  [["user_id", 1]]
=> [[1, 0], [3, 1], [2, 2]] 
2.2.0 :006 > User.last.avatars.pluck :id, :sort_order
User Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  SELECT "avatars"."id", "avatars"."sort_order" FROM "avatars"  WHERE "avatars"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "avatars"."sort_order" ASC, "avatars"."created_at" ASC  [["user_id", 2]]
=> [[4, 5], [6, 6], [5, 7]] 
2.2.0 :007 > ap User.joins(:avatars, :industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries).count
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "avatars" ON "avatars"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1)
6
=> nil 
2.2.0 :008 > ap User.joins(:avatars, :industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries).uniq.count
(0.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" INNER JOIN "avatars" ON "avatars"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1)
2
=> nil 
2.2.0 :009 > ap User.joins(:industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries).count
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1)
2
=> nil 
 2.2.0 :010 > User.joins(:industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries).each{|user| ap user.avatars }
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1)
Avatar Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "avatars".* FROM "avatars"  WHERE "avatars"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "avatars"."sort_order" ASC, "avatars"."created_at" ASC  [["user_id", 1]]
[
  [0] #<Avatar:0x007ff03f8ab448> {
            :id => 1,
       :user_id => 1,
    :sort_order => 0,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:36 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:44 UTC +00:00
},
[1] #<Avatar:0x007ff03ec7e4e0> {
            :id => 3,
       :user_id => 1,
    :sort_order => 1,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:40 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:40 UTC +00:00
},
[2] #<Avatar:0x007ff03ec7e2d8> {
            :id => 2,
       :user_id => 1,
    :sort_order => 2,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:38 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:42 UTC +00:00
}
]
Avatar Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "avatars".* FROM "avatars"  WHERE "avatars"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "avatars"."sort_order" ASC, "avatars"."created_at" ASC  [["user_id", 2]]
[
  [0] #<Avatar:0x007ff03f9121e8> {
            :id => 4,
       :user_id => 2,
    :sort_order => 5,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:44 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:48 UTC +00:00
},
[1] #<Avatar:0x007ff03f911fe0> {
            :id => 6,
       :user_id => 2,
    :sort_order => 6,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:48 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:48 UTC +00:00
},
[2] #<Avatar:0x007ff03f911dd8> {
            :id => 5,
       :user_id => 2,
    :sort_order => 7,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:46 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:48 UTC +00:00
}
]
=> [#<User id: 1, name: "John", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40">, #<User id: 2, name: "Jill", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48">] 
2.2.0 :011 > User.joins(:industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries).includes(:avatars).each{|user| ap user.avatars }

User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1)
Avatar Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "avatars".* FROM "avatars"  WHERE "avatars"."user_id" IN (1, 2)  ORDER BY "avatars"."sort_order" ASC, "avatars"."created_at" ASC
[
  [0] #<Avatar:0x007ff03c7f0df8> {
            :id => 1,
       :user_id => 1,
    :sort_order => 0,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:36 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:44 UTC +00:00
},
[1] #<Avatar:0x007ff03c7f0bf0> {
            :id => 3,
       :user_id => 1,
    :sort_order => 1,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:40 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:40 UTC +00:00
},
[2] #<Avatar:0x007ff03c7f09c0> {
            :id => 2,
       :user_id => 1,
    :sort_order => 2,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:38 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:42 UTC +00:00
}
]
[
[0] #<Avatar:0x007ff03c7f07b8> {
            :id => 4,
       :user_id => 2,
    :sort_order => 5,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:44 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:48 UTC +00:00
},
[1] #<Avatar:0x007ff03c7f0588> {
            :id => 6,
       :user_id => 2,
    :sort_order => 6,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:48 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:48 UTC +00:00
},
[2] #<Avatar:0x007ff03c7f0380> {
            :id => 5,
       :user_id => 2,
    :sort_order => 7,
    :created_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:46 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:05:48 UTC +00:00
}
]
=> [#<User id: 1, name: "John", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40">, #<User id: 2, name: "Jill", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48">]
```

Basically, we have 2 eager loading functions: preload and eager_load. When you use includes, it either calls preload or eager_load. preload results in 2 queries(find users & find avatars for retrieved users) wheres eager_load uses only 1 query(the join query). So, when includes results in an join query(ie, results in eager_load), the order of the associations to be retrieved is skipped since its a single query.

```
User.includes(:avatars, :industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries)
```

results in join cause you are filtering the users based on particular industries which in itself is a 'through' association. 'through' uses a join. Also, remember that 'joins' results in an INNER JOIN whereas eager_load uses LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
2.2.0 :050 > User.joins(:industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries)
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "John", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40">, #<User id: 2, name: "Jill", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48", updated_at: "2016-10-04 

2.2.0 :054 >   User.includes(:industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries)
SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."name" AS t0_r1, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "users"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "industries"."id" AS t1_r0, "industries"."name" AS t1_r1, "industries"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "industries"."updated_at" AS t1_r3 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "John", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40">, #<User id: 2, name: "Jill", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48">]> 

2.2.0 :057 >   User.eager_load(:industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries)
SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."name" AS t0_r1, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "users"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "industries"."id" AS t1_r0, "industries"."name" AS t1_r1, "industries"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "industries"."updated_at" AS t1_r3 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1)

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "John", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:40">, #<User id: 2, name: "Jill", created_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48", updated_at: "2016-10-04 07:05:48">]>
```

You can refer http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/ for more examples with explanation. I havent found as to why the types of joins are different. Anyways, I hope this helps. I will try to reproduce the same for later versions of rails.

Comment: Thanks, this is by far the most helpful answer so far.  Can you explain this a little better: "Includes considers the order...only when it results in a join query"? Do you mean only when it results in an INNER join query?  Because the query you can see on the README of the sample app is a LEFT OUTER JOIN and the order of avatars is disregarded.  And every query in your console log is an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail!  I just wish I could have given you one of the bounties :-/

Comment: @skensell It's fine and am glad that it helped. I came here after seeing the rails issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
@users.first.avatars[0..2].map(&:id)
# => [2546, 2547, 2548]

@users.to_a.first.avatars[0..2].map(&:id)
# => [2548, 2546, 2547]
```

> - What is going on here?

There is nothing wrong.

As per the [Guide Retrieving a Single Object Section: 1.1.3 **#first**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object)

> The first method finds the first record ordered by primary key
>   (default)

```
SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY clients.id ASC LIMIT 1
```

And the next methods which return as a collection `@users.to_a` **order by** `updated_at`

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

Because those things are different

```
# returns a user which has smallest id (@users are ordered by id)
@users.first # User::ActiveRecord_Relation#first

# is different to
# returns a first user which fetched from database (@users are unordered)
@users.to_a.first # Array#first
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, when you preloading, the order information in `avatars` association relation scope can't be used (because the "objects" to return are `User`, not `Avatar`). From SQL log, we can see that it's just join query without order on `avatars` fields.

In the case you don't use `.to_a`, the returned array is in ascending order, just so happened to be the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from including the avatars in your query. That will pull out the avatars in their natural order(id) and the `:avatars` scope won't be called as each user on the response will already have `#avatars` bound to them.

I'm afraid you'll have to reinforce the avatars order while building your query:

```
relation = User.includes(:industries,:avatars)
.where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries)
.order("users.id asc, avatars.sort_order asc, avatars.created_at asc")

avatars = relation.first.avatars
```

#### Update

To test the side effects on users order, use your initial test case and add another user within the same industry, then add an avatar with `sort_order:-1`.
`relation.pluck(:id)` will return `[1,1,1,2]`, so user order is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 bounties, I have yet to receive a satisfying answer, so I've concluded it's just a Rails bug and I've created [an issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26692) in the Rails repo on Github.

I'm posting a workaround here so others can solve their issue with a little copy-paste.

```
# in user.rb

has_many :avatars, -> { order([:sort_order => :asc,:created_at => :asc])},  dependent: :destroy
def sorted_avatars
  # sometimes the avatars scope is ignored when eagerly loaded with includes
  avatars.to_a.sort do |a1,a2|
    comp = (a1.sort_order <=> a2.sort_order)
    comp.zero? ? (a1.created_at <=> a2.created_at) : comp
  end
end
```

I will award this second bounty to Alexandre simply because his comment of changing the title of this question is more valuable to me than the current highest-voted answer.

Answer (score -1):

The prime difference between the two cases is `lazy loading` of data using `includes`.

Case 1

```
u = User.first
u.avatars.pluck(:id)
=> [1, 3, 2]
```

In this case, the sql query hit is

```
SELECT "avatars"."id" FROM "avatars"  WHERE "avatars"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY "avatars"."sort_order" ASC, "avatars"."created_at" ASC  [["user_id", 1]]
```

since you have not lazy loaded the `avatar` data here, when you try to fetch the avatar data, it hits the db and uses the sort order which you have mentioned it the model.
As you can see, the `order by` here is the one you mentioned in your scope.

Case 2

```
User.includes(:avatars, :industries).where(industries: {id: [1]}).references(:industries).first.avatars.map(&:id)
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

In this case, the sql query hit is

```
SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."name" AS t0_r1, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "users"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "avatars"."id" AS t1_r0, "avatars"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "avatars"."sort_order" AS t1_r2, "avatars"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "avatars"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "industries"."id" AS t2_r0, "industries"."name" AS t2_r1, "industries"."created_at" AS t2_r2, "industries"."updated_at" AS t2_r3 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "avatars" ON "avatars"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_industries" ON "user_industries"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "user_industries"."industry_id" WHERE "industries"."id" IN (1) AND "users"."id" IN (1)  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC
```

As you used the `includes` in above query, it is lazy loading the avatars and industires. However, it is not using the sort order you have mentioned in the avatar model while lazy loading the data, thus MySql is defaulting to `id` as sort order which gives (1,2,3)

In this case, since avatar data has already been lazy loaded, when you are running `first.avatars`, it is not hitting the DB again to fetch the `avatar` data and simply printing the data from lazy loaded values which is `[1,2,3]`